# Cannot ant runtime in Apache nutch 2.3

Tags: java, apache, ant, nutch

I followed this tutorial https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial. When I tried to run

```
ant runtime
```

I was getting this message

> BUILD FAILED
>
> /usr/local/nutch/framework/apache-nutch-2.3/build.xml:113: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> /usr/local/nutch/framework/apache-nutch-2.3/src/plugin/build.xml:35: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> /usr/local/nutch/framework/apache-nutch-2.3/src/plugin/build-plugin.xml:117: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

This is on line 117 in build-plugin.xml

> deprecation="${javac.deprecation}"

How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://github.com/momer/nutch-selenium/issues/1

Comment: So have you looked at the compiler error output for details?

Comment: I got this error     [javac] class file for java.lang.AutoCloseable not found
    [javac]       client = node.client();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. It only needed Java 7. So I ran

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

to get path like this

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

ran

```
sudo pico /etc/environment
```

set Java home folder path

> JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"

and finally ran

```
 source /etc/environment
```